# Twilio Chat User creation friendlyName

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to make a chat sandboxing api, aka creating the user, channel and adding the user to the channel. The problem is that every time i call the restApi to create a new user, it doesn't take the attributes or the friendlyName. The code is the following:

```
$user->chat->services($serviceSid)->users->create(
        array(
            'identity'     => $identity,
            'friendlyName' => $friendlyName,
            'attributes'   => $attributes,
            'roleSid'      => $roleSid
        )
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your code to create the user isn't quite right there. `create` takes the identity as the first argument and then the optional arguments in an array as the second. Try this instead:

```
$user->chat->services($serviceSid)->users->create(
    $identity,
    array(
        'friendlyName' => $friendlyName,
        'attributes'   => $attributes,
        'roleSid'      => $roleSid
    )
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem. I was looking at the documentation on the website and it only contained the identity for PHP and i corelated that with Node and the rest and i thought it all had to be in the array. Thanks.

Comment: Why in the HE DOUBLE HOCKEY STICKS is this not mentioned in the documentation?  Up-voted!